# Search wordpress media library by attached post title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have over 18,000 images in my media library, all attached to thousands of posts as they were uploaded when the posts were created.

By default it seems Wordpress only lets you search for images in the media library by its filename. Unfortunately this is no good as a lot of my files have crazy GUID style names, not keywords that relate to the post they are attached to.

Is there a way I can modify the search so that it also searches by attached post title? I've looked at a number of plugins but they only extend media searching by also including other media fields like title, alternative description, caption, etc. They don't search in attached post titles.

Any help greatly received!

Comment: wordpress and that media-library... it's a mess

Comment: May be you should try jetpack pervious version that have post and uploaded file search.